# Xilinx FPGA Error :FPGA Programming Failed due to errors while initializing bitstream

Tags: fpga, xilinx-edk

I have a problem in loading my program in FPGA ,I got this error:

```
FATAL:Data2MEM:44 - Out of memory allocating 'getMemory' object of 960000000 bytes.
    Total memory already in use is 14823 bytes.
    Source file "../s/DeviceTableUtils.c", line number 5692.
```

FPGA Programming Failed due to errors while initializing bitstream.

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me today, with an error message starting with:

```
FATAL:Data2MEM:44 - Out of memory allocating 'getMemory' object of 960000000 bytes.
```

The solution for me, was to simply reboot my computer (this has been mentioned in some places on the web too, including [this Xilinx Forums thread](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Vivado-Debug-and-Power/data2mem-error-quot-FATAL-Data2MEM-44-quot/td-p/176368)).